# Directive decorator in config block never called

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using angularJS 1.4.9 and ui bootstrap 1.0.3.
I would like to decor uibDatepicker directive but the decorator function is never executed and there is no error or warning message in the console.
[See this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HjKKPvt8h8jsiZ1xMXjn?p=preview)

```
var uib = angular.module('ui.bootstrap');
uib.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('uibDatepickerDirective', function($delegate) {
    alert('never logs this');
    return $delegate;
});

var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  var main = this;
  main.welcome = 'hello you';

});
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: It's not executed because you never actually use this directive in your HTML. Here is the demo with directive in HTML: http://plnkr.co/edit/p4Hcgz83wv9d1WOl6eGo?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decorator function is never executed because you never actually use this directive you are trying to decorate.

Decorator is going to be invoked only when the directive is requested by real element in template. This is because services and directives are lazily configured (providers) so provider will not be active unless the service or directive is requested.

Here is an example of it being called when you put directive tag in template. Try adding this line in your code:

```
<uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" class="well well-sm"></uib-datepicker>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/p4Hcgz83wv9d1WOl6eGo?p=preview